# ionic $state.go is working async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Every since ios9 update my $state.go is not working sync. I have this piece of code in my ionic application

```
$state.go('layout.categories');
window.location.reload();
```

Simple right well the state.go transition do a full page refresh.
The problem I'm having is that $state.go doesn't finish before my window.location.reload triggers.

I found this work around.

```
$state.go('layout.categories');
setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.reload();
}, 20)
```

But as you can see it is really messy and it looks really weird. I was wondering if any of you guys encounter this problem if so, do you have any tips for a rookie.

Thanks.

Comment: why you want to reload using `window.location.reload()` after `state.go()`??

Comment: I want to clear a whole bunch of nodes in my application by doing a full page reload all the unwanted element are gone.

Comment: Well, whatever is going on at your end is mystery but that is not the right approach. You should check why you have those unwanted elements rather than applying these kind of patches. When your code base grow this will eventually catch up to you otherwise.

Comment: The reason your window reload work in `setTimeout` is because it let `state.go()` to complete along with the transition which is default in ionic when you switch views. So `setTimeout` has set the code to execute later i.e. 20ms after `state.go()`.